# How to add else into PHP Code line?

Tags: php

I have this following code

```
    <td>    
    <?php if($rec->telegram){ ?><a href="<?php echo $rec->telegram;  ?>"><img class="social" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>social/telegram.jpg" /><?php } ?></a>
    <?php if($rec->google_pluse){ ?><a href="<?php echo $rec->google_pluse;  ?>"><img class="social" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>social/g.jpg" /><?php } ?></a>
    <?php if($rec->instagram){ ?><a href="<?php echo $rec->instagram;  ?>"><img class="social" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>social/insta.jpg" /><?php } ?></a>
    <?php if($rec->facebook){ ?><a href="<?php echo $rec->facebook;  ?>"><img class="social" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>social/f.jpg" /><?php } ?></a>
    </td>
```

I would like to add **"else"** into this code that if **ALL those icons** facebook, instagram, google plus and facebook **weren't available** then it will show another image file like **"nophoto.jpg"**

Note: If all those icons (4 icons) weren't available then it will show nophoto.jpg

I highly appreciate if someone guide me how to add else into above code.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should take the use of PHP's conditional operators like this:

```
<?php
  $icons_available = (
      !empty($rec->telegram) &&
      !empty($rec->google_plus) &&
      !empty($rec->instagram) &&
      !empty($rec->facebook)
  );
?>

<td>
    <?php if(!$icons_available)  { ?>
        <a href="default-pic.jpg">
            <img class="social" src="default-pic.jpg" />
        </a>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <?php $url = echo base_url() . 'social/telegram.jpg'; ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">
            <img class="social" src="<?php echo $url ?>" />
        </a>

        <?php $url = echo base_url() . 'social/google_plus.jpg'; ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $url ?>">
            <img class="social" src="<?php echo $url ?>" />
        </a>

        <?php $url = echo base_url() . 'social/instagram.jpg'; ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $url ?>">
            <img class="social" src="<?php echo $url ?>" />
        </a>

        <?php $url = echo base_url() . 'social/facebook.jpg'; ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $url ?>">
            <img class="social" src="<?php echo $url ?>" />
        </a>
    <?php } ?>
</td>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will show the nophoto icon multiple times which isn't the behaviour desired by the OP.

Comment: Those icons not loading, As I mentioned, If ALL of them not available then nophoto will be shown, if one of them is available, it;s okay , just only all of them not available, with your code, even available icons also now showing

Answer (score 0):

It'll be easier to just add an extra if:

```
if (!($rec->telegram || $rec->instagram || $rec->facebook || $rec->google_plus)) { //etc
```

But really you want to attach that kind of logic to the `$rec` object, so that it's neatly separated and it's easier to add new types of social media in the future. Hopefully your `$rec` object is indeed backed by a class and not just a `stdClass` from a database result or cast.

```
public function hasNoSocialIcon() {
    return !($rec->telegram || $rec->instagram || $rec->facebook  || $rec->google_plus);
}
```

And then use that in your template:

```
<?php if ($rec->hasNoSocialIcon()) { ?>
  <img class="social" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>social/nophoto.jpg" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: could you make it into one section that I'll just copy it and paste it instead of my code? Thank you, cause I really don't know PHP

Comment: Then hire a freelancer or learn. This isn't the place to come to have someone write code for you.